# DNS Problem and question mark in top bar - Ubuntu 17

Tags: wireless, internet, dns, browser

I'm not sure why I can't connect to the Internet.

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 17 with Windows 10 - On my Windows OS, WiFi works fine but when I start Ubuntu on the pnezl a **?** is shown instead of the WiFi  or LAN icon:
[image: Network Icon]
Also when I go in the browser (Firefox, Chrome) I get this message: `This site cannot be reached.`

[image: DNS Error]

I'm not sure where should I start with analyzing the problem.

I didn't have this problem while I used Ubuntu 16

Comment: Steps would be: 1) does WiFi work 2) does DNS work 3) does browsing work. Doing it in any other order would be a waste of time.

Comment: Clearly your Wifi connection is not running correctly, so you will have to fix that first.

Comment: How od I can check all of these steps? Sorry for maybe stupid question, but I'm newbie in Ubuntu

I'm sure that my hardware for WiFi works good (Because I can connect on Windows - dual boot)

Comment: Do you see your Wifi network among the list of all networks? When you choose it do you enter the correct password or key? What happens next?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.10. Was however able to open web pages in the **Tor Browser** but not in Firefox or Chrome. I solved this by carefully following the steps in the following article by Hectic Geek. 
*Possibly one only needs to follow the part after the title **End of Update***
 https://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/

Was not however able to get rid of the question mark. It is however a known bug, as shown in the following bug report
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1722256
Report also suggests a possible simple solution to both issues.

Edit:- it appears that the question mark issue is related to the curl package installed, see
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229189

Answer (score 0):

I went into WiFi settings, turned DNS Auto off, and used 8.8.8.8 (Google's free DNS server address); that worked for me.

Comment: This looks like a network *interface* issue though.